# NGinx reverse proxy but jquery fail

Tags: jquery, nginx, proxy

I use NGinx to redirect my JBoss application : 
http://mywebsite.com:8283 --> http://test.mywebsite.com

This solution work, but some modules doesn't work like jquery:

Console error

```
POST http://mywebsite.com/SaikuIS/rest/saiku/USER/query/2F70DD1F-3449-…antillon.AllSampleTypes%5D.%5BToutes%20les%20types%20d'%C3%A9chantillon%5D 400 (Illegal character in path at index 152: http://mywebsite.com/SaikuIS/rest/saiku/USER/query/2F70DD1F-3449-574E-9326-26DC27F53E25/axis/COLUMNS/dimension/Type%20d'echantillon/hierarchy/[Type%20d'echantillon.AllSampleTypes]/[Type%20d'echantillon.AllSampleTypes].[Toutes%20les%20types%20d'%c3%a9chantillon])
```

proxy.conf

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name test.mywebsite.*;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8283/;
        }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please [post the solution to your question as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not an edit in your original question.

Comment: For anyone looking for solution checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files