# The LINK CSS in the HTML is no use online? Everything is all right

Tags: html, css, django, browser, nginx

It is all right in development environment, but online.

The site `url`: 
    http://www.petanne.com/chart/

The CSS `url`:
    http://www.petanne.com/static/css/chart.css

All of them can be visited. But the `css is no use`. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Other: I use `nginx` act as agent for static files. It is a `django` project.

Comment: It looks like the browser is not read css.

Comment: I use http://validator.w3.org to check this url. It is nothing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is serving `.css` files with **MIME** type `text/plain`. It should be `text/css`. Just tell your server administrator and they will fix it for you.

If you see the console in chrome, it says:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type `text/plain`.

And in firefox:

> The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, `"text/plain"`, is not `"text/css"`.

Comment: I found an workaround on the http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875443/2416308. Add `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` to nginx.conf, In location /static/ {}. It will make sure the right mime types.

Answer (score 0):

See [Validator results](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.petanne.com%2Fchart%2F)

You have several errors, including the CSS part:

> Line 23, Column 69: end tag for "link" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified
>
> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to
>   "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

Anyways, despite the CSS line, take a look at the results and try to fix all errors, these are very easy fixes and will make your page work properly

Comment: I just fix it. The validator.w3.org is passed now. But the css is no use yet.