# videojs controller is plain text?

Tags: nginx, video.js

I configured nginx to HLS and make videojs html. But I see that video controller is displayed like plain text instead button. I downloaded new videojs and put it w/o any changes, but I still see same issue. Also I see it on another PC with another OS.

Please see image
http://s019.radikal.ru/i637/1410/e4/25e659df53b9.png

Play change to Pause on plain text when I do mouse click.

Do you know what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've used the video.js script, but not the css stylesheet.

Comment: Hi, I didn't change anything in original videojs sample. I checked in chrome dev tools, it don't have any issues with css.

Answer (score 0):

it's nginx issue, need update config and include mime.type for CSS support

[Nginx fails to load css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files)