# CSS was not loaded because its MIME type

Tags: css, nginx

I use nginx, I have include mime.types and I keep having error when I try access my css files. I tried insert "include /etc/nginx/mime.types;" in "location /" but didn't works.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
upstream test_server {
  server unix:/var/www/test/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ec2-#-#-#-#.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/www/test/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/test/logs/nginx-error.log warn;

    location /static/ {
          autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/test/my-example/static/;
          include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/test/my-example/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://test_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    #For favicon
    location  /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/test/test/static/img/favicon.ico;
    }
    #For robots.txt
    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/test/test/static/robots.txt ;
    }
    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /var/www/test/my-example/static/;
    }
}

}
```

And head of my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../static/css/combo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../static/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="../static/css/raleway.css">
```

But I keep having this error:

> was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx fails to load css files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files)

Comment: What is the address of your html page?

Comment: @J.Titus Did you read when I say "I have include mime.types?

Comment: @DanielaMorais Did you look at the answer of the linked question? I don't see that in your conf file.

Comment: @J.Titus Of course I tried do this before post here (include in location / and not in location /static/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is usual to place `include mime.types;` inside the outer `http { ... }` block, rather than inside a `location { ... }` block, so that it is system-wide and inherited by all `server { ... }` blocks and all locations.

Your `href="../static/css/` statement is relative, so from the information you provide, we cannot tell whether the URI is being processed by the `location /static/` block or the `location /` block.

You do not have a `root` (or `alias`) defined for the `location /` block, so the false condition of the `if (!-f $request_filename)` statement will probably always fail with 404.

You may want to set `root /var/www/test/my-example` in the `server { ... }` block and allow it to be inherited by some `location` blocks. The use of `alias` where a `root` can be used is discouraged - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

If your CSS files are being served through the `proxy_pass http://test_server;` then this is the wrong place to be fixing the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is modifying `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and put

```
    types {
    ....
    text/css     css plain;
    ....
   }
```