# Moodle 3.0 - CSS and Javascript don't load - Requests to NGINX aren't compatible with the real paths

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, moodle

My config:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Nginx 1.4.6
- PHP 5.5.9
- Moodle 3.0

I've completed the Moodle 3.0 installation through the browser and there is no css or javascript loaded. This is NGINX error log:

```
2017/04/24 20:48:23 [error] 3277#0: *601 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:23 [error] 3277#0: *601 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:23 [error] 3277#0: *601 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:24 [error] 3277#0: *609 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/styles.php/clean/1493057621/all" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/styles.php/clean/1493057621/all HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:24 [error] 3277#0: *611 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/javascript-static.js" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/javascript-static.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:24 [error] 3277#0: *611 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:24 [error] 3277#0: *606 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:24 [error] 3277#0: *606 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:25 [error] 3277#0: *609 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/javascript-static.js" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/javascript-static.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:25 [error] 3277#0: *609 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/image.php/clean/core/1493057621/moodlelogo HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:25 [error] 3277#0: *609 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /lib/javascript.php/1493057621/lib/requirejs/require.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
2017/04/24 20:48:25 [error] 3277#0: *609 open() "/var/www/html/moodle/theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /theme/javascript.php/clean/1493057621/footer HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"
```

It seems that the path is considering some .php files to be directories.
This is my server config:

```
server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name localhost;

    # Root #
    root /var/www/html/moodle/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            rewrite ^ 404;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I have already tried these solutions:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files)

[Solution 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/240743/nginx-cant-load-images-css-jshttp://)

They didn't work...

Comment: Your error messages display `.php` scripts with pathinfo, but your configuration does not support pathinfo. See [this recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for guidance.

Comment: @RichardSmith I read the article you've send, added some changes to my code, but it was almost the same that I did and nothing happened. My code has the fastcgi_split_path_info slightly different from the one on the article. I still have the same issue...

Comment: Your `location ~ \.php$` statement only accepts URIs without pathinfo. The final `$` means they finish after the `.php`. That maybe all you need to change.

Comment: @RichardSmith man, I tried your fix and it dind't work out. The problem is: the path has to end with .php, otherwise the further slashes will tell the interpreter that the php file is a directory. That's weird...

Comment: Did you find any fixd for this?

Comment: @FranciscoCaviano Sorry to take too long to answer you. The thing is that I don't remember if I got a solution for this. I managed to install Moodle with PHP 7.x on Ubuntu 16.04, then I guess I moved on. I'll look at my notes and if I find something about the solution to this, I'll answer my own question with it.

Comment: I found [this documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Nginx) at Moodle Site about Nginx configuration, but I couldn't solve this problem neither.

Answer (score 12):

Please add below configuration code on your server part of nginx.conf file.

```
location / {
             root /var/www/yourwebsite.com;
             index index.php index.html index.htm;

             # moodle rewrite rules
             rewrite ^/(.*.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;
          }

      # php parsing
      location ~ .php$ {
                         root /var/www/yourwebsite.com;
                         try_files $uri =404;
                         fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                         fastcgi_index index.php;
                         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                          include fastcgi_params;
                          fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                          fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                          fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                          fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

               }
```

Comment: Definitely Solved my problem. Thank You!!

Answer (score 8):

Heres my plain nginx config which works fine for moodle >=3.1

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name someservername.com;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

}
```

Comment: What worked for me was the `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` and the `fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` parts.

Comment: For me, `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;` was what fixed it