# Firefox transforming text/css to text/plain (NGINX server)

Tags: html, css, firefox, nginx, mime-types

I'm mounting a server with nginx, and I have some issue with my css. On IE it's well displayed, but the firefox's console says me that my css files were not loaded because their mime type is text/plain and not text/css.

In my server, I've got this into the "mime.types" file :

```
text/css css;
```

I have included mime.types in my nginx.conf :

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

And in my index.html, my stylesheet is imported this way :

```
<link href = "./css/stable.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
@import "./css/style.css";
</style>
```

My js files are recognized as .js by firefox, the issue is only with .css files, I don't understand why (and why this is working on IE)

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Use `curl -v` and check the value of the `content-type` HTTP header.

Comment: I have text/html

Comment: So the problem comes from your Nginx configuration and not from Firefox. Do you have some warnings in the Nginx logs?

Comment: Did you check this: [Nginx fails to load css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files?rq=1) ?

Comment: Yes I've already checked this, I try to reinstall everything and I'll tell you how it goes. I didn't have warnings due to this in the logs, thanks for your answers

Comment: @JeanDupont did you manage to solve this ? I am having this issue as well. Would like to know if you have found a solution. Thanks

Comment: In fact I was trying to install an application manually, but I have found a script that installs it automatically so I've used it like a lazy person. I don't have answers for you, sorry