# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am running a Rails 5 application on AWS and have configured the nginx with following `nginx.conf` file. 
The problem is my application.css file is served with wrong mime type by nginx. Can someone point out what went out wrong please?

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
   http {

            include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type  application/octet-stream;
            sendfile     on;
            tcp_nopush   on;

            upstream puma {
              server unix:/home/deployer/website/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
            }

            server {
              listen 80 default_server deferred;
              # server_name example.com;

              root /home/deployer/website/current/public;
              access_log /home/deployer/website/current/log/nginx.access.log;
              error_log /home/deployer/website/current/log/nginx.error.log info;


              location ~* ^/assets/ {
                gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css application/xml application/json;
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
              }

              try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
              location @puma {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_pass http://puma;
              }

              error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
              client_max_body_size 10M;
              keepalive_timeout 10;
            }
   }
```

Update: Although, not able to get Nginx to return CSS with a correct mime type, I worked around the issue with some client-side Javascript(fix obtained from a blog for another issue). Here is the code which I put in my `application.js`.

```
    /* Fix for font awesome icons disappearing on reload*/
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-render", function(event) {
      FontAwesome.dom.i2svg({
        node: event.data.newBody
      });
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files and see if anything could help you there.

Comment: I've read and tried those already. Doesn't seem to work out. Some client-side javascript mentioned in post fixed the rendering issue for now.