# Build script from create-react-app adds an external import into CSS

Tags: css, node.js, npm, create-react-app

I have an app created with create-react-app. The app works fine when served using `npm run start`.

Now, when built using `npm run build`, some CSS seems missing. I also observe that `build/static/css/main.38396655.css` contains an `@import` to a third-party server. Namely for Esri's Calcite Components: `@import url("https://js.arcgis.com/4.25/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css")`.

Furthermore, the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools does not show any request for that imported file. I also get no 404 or anything if I replace it by a non-existing URL.

Two questions regarding this:

1. Does this external import actually cause the missing CSS?
2. If so, how can I force the build script to include this CSS in the built package?

As requested, here also the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@arcgis/core": "^4.25.5",
    "@esri/calcite-components": "^1.0.5",
    "@esri/calcite-components-react": "^0.35.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In your browser if you `Inspect Element` then refresh the page, do you see any errors in the `console` or `network` tabs relating to your `.css` file?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors shown at all. The console does not report anything at all, and network has all responses with statuscode 200.

Answer (score 1):

I could finally solve the problem on my own:

The CSS file was never really loaded, because nginx served it with a wrong mime type. So finally it was a problem with nginx, not CSS, that I solved as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749319/prevent-nginx-from-serving-css-files-as-text-plain).

Unfortunately, the dev tools neither in Chrome nor Edge said anything about the mime type problem. It was finally the Mozilla dev tools that gave me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're missing the `"` quotation markers around the URL itself inside the import. Look at [Importing CSS Rules](https://@import%20url(https://js.arcgis.com/4.25/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css)).

Try using this:

`@import url("https://js.arcgis.com/4.25/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css")`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help either. First of all, the `@import url(...)` appears in a file that is not manually edited, but the result of `npm run build` by `create-react-app`. Second, even when I add the quotation marks, the problem stays the same.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share your `package.json` file contents in the original post? I'd like to help.

Comment: Did so. It's also to mention that the dev tools in Chrome don't show any request to the imported file. But it definitely exists.