# Nginx can't load static files, did I set wrong path?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I tried setting up nginx with docker on my django project.

I checked the volume exists on docker container. And I do have access to my swagger path, but staticfiles does not load.

What else can I attempt? Thanks...

For example, as settings.py has set the path:

```
# Static files
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

and here is nginx/nginx.conf, may see locaiotn in http:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream django {
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        server_name localhost;
        access_log off;
        listen 80;

        location /static/ {
            alias /app/staticfiles/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, docker-compose script:

```
version: '3.8'

  services:
    web:
      build: .
      command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 120 --workers 3
      volumes:
        - .:/app
        - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - redis
    nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      depends_on:
        - web
......
  volumes:
    static_volume:
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it should work if it's not docker or nginx issues

Comment: Yes, I tried both. `python manage.py collectstatic` and `docker compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic` Yet, still not working. Please note: docker compose exec web ls /app/staticfiles:
And I have these(collectfiles): admin           drf-yasg        rest_framework

Answer (score 0):

Case solved. It was type definition issue from nginx.conf.

Let nginx to identify the file types.

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types
```

[Nginx fails to load css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files)