# Issue with Nginx serving Hugo static files with proper theme

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I’m facing an issue where the site loads fine with the hugo server command, but when served through Nginx with static files, the theme doesn’t load correctly.

nginx Configuration (Hugo Server)):

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1313; 
        }
    }
}
```

nginx Configuration (Static files):

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /Users/pramodchoudhari/personal_projects/my_blog/promode_me/public/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Hugo Command for Public Directory Generation:

```
hugo --theme hugo-PaperMod
```

Hugo Server Command:

```
hugo server -D
```

This is how the site loads when i try to serve the static files using nginx
[image]

This is the console log:
[image]

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I have added the console log screenshot in the question

Comment: Your stylesheet is being loaded (as you can see in your console). However, that stylesheet is probably empty as you can see in your browser. There are no styles visible. You should look what is inside that stylesheet and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875443/6180721

```
include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

This was missing in nginx.conf.